# Exploding a zip into a dependency

Tags: gradle, nexus

There is a zip file(specifically, it is a selenium zip file) on Nexus that I need to unzip and add to my project's dependencies. At work Nexus is locked down so it is a pain to get anything on there or I'd just unzip the file there myself. I don't know how to accomplish this since I run into a circular dependency.

Is there a way to make this work?

Here is sample code:

```
configurations{
    selenium
}

dependencies {
    selenium 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium:3.1.0@zip'
}

task unzip(type: Copy) {
    configurations.selenium.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each { artifact ->
        if (artifact.file.name.endsWith('.zip')) {
            from zipTree(artifact.file)
            into outputDir

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an inelegant solution.

```
    def outputDir = file('Dependency location')
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: outputDir) 
    }
    compileJava.doFirst { tasks.unzip.execute() }

    task unzip(type: Copy) {
    def f = new File(outputDir, 'selenium zip file')
    new URL('Nexus url to selenium zip').withInputStream { -> f.withOutputStream { it << i }}

    FileTree zip = zipTree(f)
    from (zip)
    into outputDir
}
```